# Unable to Get options when adding sprites in Godot engine

Tags: game-development, godot

whenever i drag and drop a sprite from my assets folder it gets added straight as a node to the scene but never ask for options like you see in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUV5Z.png). I am a beginner and do not understand why is this happening. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the node type menu that you're looking for, hold `alt` when you drag and drop. (Tested in v3.2 stable)

Comment: It Works! Thank You

Comment: No problem. You can also change the node type by right clicking on it in the node viewer and selecting "change type".

Comment: For future reference, if you're on Linux, your window manager may be intercepting the use of the Alt + mouse button combination. To solve this, change your window management's modifier key to Meta.